# How can I configure the "delete" key to delete a word in c shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh, xterm

I tried to do "stty werase [3~", "stty werase ^H" " stty werase ^?" , but nothing has helped.
Do you have any idea how to configure the DEL / delete key to delete a word in c shell?

Thanks,

Comment: The code(s) sent by the delete key can vary.  What do see when you type control-V DEL ?

Comment: When I typr control-V DEL I get "^[[3~"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using tcsh rather than csh, this should work:

```
bindkey '^[[3~' backward-delete-word
```

I don't think `stty` can map multi-character sequences, but you might be able to configure your terminal emulator so that <kbd>Delete</kbd> sends an ASCII DEL character.  In xterm, right-click and enable the "Delete is DEL" option, or set the X resource:

```
XTerm*deleteIsDEL:      True
```

You can then use

```
stty werase '^?'
```

(the single quotes aren't actually necessary).  Other terminal emulators should also have some mechanism to cause <kbd>Delete</kbd> to send ASCII DEL.